# How do I read bool columns from SQLite into bool Clojure values with next.jdbc? SQLite stores booleans as 0/1

Tags: sqlite, jdbc, clojure

Here's the smallest bit of code to see the problem.

```clj
  (require '[next.jdbc :as jdbc])

  (def db-spec {:dbtype "sqlite" :dbname "example-db"})

  (jdbc/execute!
   db-spec
   ["create table if not exists users (name text, is_active bool)"])

  (jdbc/execute!
   db-spec
   ["insert into users (name, is_active) values (?, ?)" "alice" true])

  (jdbc/execute!
   db-spec
   ["select * from users"])
  ;; => [#:users{:name "alice", :is_active 1}]
```

I'd like `is_active` on that last line to be `true` or `false`. I don't want my application code to have to keep track of which columns are bool and do conversion after I get a result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next.jdbc` gives you several ways to plug into how it creates Clojure objects from database values. The most general of these is by passing a `:builder-fn` option with a value created from `builder-adapter` and passing your own (or an existing) builder and a custom "read-column-by-index"

```clj
  (require '[next.jdbc.result-set :as rs])
  (defn sqlite-column-by-index-fn [builder ^ResultSet rs ^Integer i]
    (let [rsm ^ResultSetMetaData (:rsmeta builder)]
      (rs/read-column-by-index
       (if (re-find #"(?i)(bool|bit)" (.getColumnTypeName rsm i))
         (.getBoolean rs i)
         (.getObject rs i))
       rsm
       i)))
  (def sqlite-builder (rs/builder-adapter rs/as-maps sqlite-column-by-index-fn))
  (jdbc/execute!
   db/db-spec
   ["select id, \"email-confirmed?\" from user;"]
   {:builder-fn sqlite-builder})
  ;; => [#:user{:id 1, :email-confirmed? true} #:user{:id 2, :email-confirmed? false}]
```

NOTE: This won't always work if your using `plan`. For performance, `plan` doesn't realize values. In your reduction of a plan, accessing values of the result set will skip over the custom read-column-by-index stuff above. It's up to you to do the work in your reduction.

More info, from the author of `next.jdbc`, can be found at https://github.com/seancorfield/next-jdbc/blob/develop/doc/tips-and-tricks.md#sqlite and https://github.com/seancorfield/next-jdbc/issues/134

---

The rest of this answer is lagniappe. It's the "almost-there" and wrong turns that I made along the way. I'm leaving it as part of the answer for whatever value that may provide.

`next.jdbc` lets you extend the `ReadableColumn` protocol with custom functionality for converting values.

https://github.com/seancorfield/next-jdbc/blob/develop/doc/result-set-builders.md#readablecolumn

```clj
(extend-protocol result-set/ReadableColumn
  Integer
  (read-column-by-index [x mrs i]
    (if (re-find #"(?i)bool" (.getColumnTypeName mrs i))
      (if (= 1 x) true false)
      x)))
```

It might not be perfect. There's another function, `read-column-by-label`, that doesn't receive the `ResultSetMetaData` object that we can call `getColumnTypeName` on to test if the column type is a bool. `read-column-by-label` only receives the value and the column name. I'm not sure what the consequences of not overriding that function. Things appear to work with just `read-column-by-index` overridden.

Editing to make note of how this isn't a complete fix.

`plan`, for example, returns a reducible. The reduce function gets passed a "mapified" result set. Some of the implementations of some of the interfaces call `read-column-by-label`. I think it does this for performance reasons? So you can do something like `select-keys` without "building" the entire map. So if you want to do something like below with the reducer, then the above fix isn't sufficient.

```
  (def plan (jdbc/plan db-spec ["select * from users;"]))
  (defn reduce-fn [a b]
    (conj a (select-keys b [:users/name :users/is_active])))
  (r/reduce reduce-fn [] plan)
  ;; => [#:users{:name "alice", :is_active 1}
  ;;     #:users{:name "bob", :is_active 0}]

  (jdbc/execute! db-spec ["select * from users;"])
  ;; => [#:users{:name "alice", :is_active true, :age 1}
  ;;     #:users{:name "bob", :is_active false, :age 0}]
```

Comment: `plan` calls may break if you do not also override `read-column-by-label` (not `name`).

Comment: Thanks. I thought that might be the case. I tried (r/foldcat (jdbc/plan datasource ["select * from users;"]))) with the example code in the question and it worked. I'll keep digging, but if I can't figure it out can you expand on under what circumstances it would break?

Comment: Great to see you updated the answer here to reflect the latest information -- thank you!